# Computer partially waking from sleep every hour

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, power

From `powercfg /sleepstudy`:

[image: sleepstudy report]

Over long periods in modern standby, my laptop briefly transitions from sleep to screen off and back again almost exactly every hour. I'd like to stop this from happening.

`powercfg /waketimers` displays only one timer:
`Timer set by [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe expires at 04:00:00 on .` which does not seem to account for any of the wakes seen in the report above.

`powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` shows only `HID-compliant mouse`, which definitely was not touched during sleep mode.

The reason given for each wake is specified in the report as `Transition from Sleep` which doesn't seem to narrow it down to any particular piece of hardware or software:
[image: screen off state]

How can I determine what's causing my laptop to wake every hour? How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: There is no normal app or process that wakes up a computer hourly.  Updates might wake it up once in two weeks or something similar.  Update BIOS and Power Driver (if one), restart and test.

Comment: What does powercfg /lastwake show?

Comment: @John Lenovo Vantage claims that all my firmware is up to date

Comment: @Moab It just says 'Wake History Count = 0'

Comment: Try the following from an Admin Command Prompt. (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  followed by (2) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by (3) SFC /SCANNOW  .  Allow all to finish, restart and test again.

Comment: I ran those commands; seems like no issues were found. I'll report back later if I keep getting hourly wakes: https://i.imgur.com/lTk4fZB.png

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have helped. Here's a new sleepstudy which also shows random wakes delayed by approximately one hour: https://i.imgur.com/u4WeAFq.png